# Angular console exception

Tags: angular

I'm getting this console exception in angular 6:

```
_co.user.address is undefined
```

This is the json object info received from service:

```
{"name":"John Doe","address":{"city":"Las Vegas"}}
```

This is the web page code:

```
<p>UserName: {{ user.name }} </p>
<p>City: {{ user.address.city }} </p>
```

And this is the user class ts code:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Object;
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
      this.data.getUser().subscribe(
        data => this.user = data
      );
    }
 }
```

However, city information in web page is showing correctly.

Comment: You need to check if user actually has data, use *ngIf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`safe navigation operator(?)`** to handle the console error since the data is being retrieved asynchronously

```
<p>UserName: {{ user?.name }} </p>
<p>City: {{ user?.address?.city }} </p>
```

You can also use *ngIf if you are binding lot of variables on the template,

```
<ng-template *ngIf="user">
    <p>UserName: {{ user?.name }} </p>
    <p>City: {{ user?.address?.city }} </p>
</ng-template>
```